# Cannot find Class with php namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Hi guys im getting an error when i try to use namespace  like this. here is the first error whene running the code below.

```
Fatal error: Class B\C\ClassC' not found
```

// file: index.php

```
define("DS",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("__PATH__",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include (__PATH__.DS.'B'.DS.'autoloader.php');
use A\ClassA;
$obj = new classA();
```

// file: B/autoloader.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once __PATH__.DS.$class.'.php';
});
```

// file: A/ClassA.php

```
namespace A;
use B\ClassB;
class ClassA extends ClassB{}
```

// file: B/ClassB.php

```
namespace B;
use B\C\ClassC;
class ClassB extends ClassC{}
```

// file: B/C/ClassC.php

```
namespace B\C;
class ClassC{}
```

Comment: I have tried the same code. I am not getting any error

Comment: TY for inspiration and a simplest autoloader function, here it just needed to str_replace() the \ to / and it was good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Unless beginning with a `\`, all namespace references are relative to current namespace:

```
namespace Foo;
use Bar\Baz;    // refers to \Foo\Bar\Baz
use \Bar\Baz;   // refers to \Bar\Baz
```

Comment: same problem Fatal error: Class B\C\ClassC' not found thank you for your response